# Issues with creating login form with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I drew out the logic for this feature on paper first so it made some sense where I was going with this. I have the form being created, the form calls a method in the control class on submit and then sent to the model for checking.

I belive the logic in my controller is correct, so the issue I think is with the method inside the model class.

```
function validate()
{
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password', $this->input->post('password'));
    $query = $this->db->get('membership');

    return $query;  
}
```

I expected $query to return true or false, like a boolean would. Instead whatever its outputting appears to be true no matter if the inputted data matches that in the database or if its completely wrong. Below is the method in the controller class;

```
function validate_credentials()
{       
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->createAdminForm();
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->model('admin_Model');

        $query = $this->admin_Model->validate();

        if($query)
        {
            redirect('pages');
        }
        else // incorrect username or password
        {
            $this->createAdminForm();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use different way, I think is more clear:

```
public function login(){


        if($this->input->post('login')){

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|callback_valid_login');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|callback_valid_password');

            if($this->form_validation->run($this)){
                $user = $this->user_model->get_by_field('username', $this->input->post('username'));

                $this->session->set_userdata($user);

                redirect("pages");
            } else {
                $this->load->view('login_failed');
            }
        } else
            $this->load->view('login');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found my own answer, changed the validate() method to this

```
function validate()
{
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password', $this->input->post('password'));
    $query = $this->db->get('membership');

    if($query->num_rows != 0)
    {
        $validate=true;
        return $validate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `$validate = true; return $validate` you can simply say `return TRUE`.